# YouTube Data API no longer returns deleted videos in playlists?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get list of all my liked videos on YouTube (including deleted) using [playlistItems.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) method.

Last month (Sep. 2018) I've tried it, response from the server contained exact amount of items, including every video with '[Deleted video]' title.

Currently (Oct. 2018), response looks like this: [chrome console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oc1yk.png) (note the '48': means two deleted videos is missing in the array).

I've checked out [revision history](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/revision_history), but there is no mention about recent changes related to this problem.

---

**So my questions is**:

Does playlistItems.list method no longer return deleted videos in playlists?

If yes, does anyone have a link to changelog or any ideas on how to get deleted video id now?

Or it's just me messed up something and everything works the old way?

---

**EDIT**: Found related [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110132583) on google issue tracker.
But it's dated **Jun. 14, 2018** which is strange, since for me everything worked back in June.

Comment: Reported another issue on the YouTube bug tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/121017800

Answer (score 0):

I do remember testing this before June 18' and the total was **never** reflecting the actual results, I see others acknowledge this as well [refer to this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35174190)